# An Address is Printed Instead of the Expected Value

Tags: c

I am trying to write a simple program. I am a begineer and i am not getting a value to total. When i am trying to print . I am getting a address as output . Can anyone explain me what is the mistake and correct my program .

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int first,second,total;
    printf("enter the value for the first");
    scanf("%d",&first);
    printf("enter the value for the second");
    scanf("%d",&second);
    total=power(first,second);
    printf("The value for power is %d",power);
} 

int power(int doom1,int doom2)
{
    int temp=doom1;
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<=doom2;i++)
    {
            temp=temp*doom1;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: No matter what compilers let you get away with, function `main` is type `int` and returns a value to the caller. So the correct declaration is `int main (void) {...` and then at the end `return 0;` (or some meaningful **positive** value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the wrong variable:

```
total=power(first,second); //here you are getting return value in variable total
printf("The value for power is %d",power);  // power is the function name not variable
```

Replace this line with:

```
printf("The value for power is %d",total);  // you need to print `total`
```

Also you have to declare your function prototype before `main()`:

```
int power(int ,int);
```

and you should use `int main()`:

```
int main()
{
    // your code
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to passing `total` to `printf` instead of `power`, as you are just starting, make a point to always give your variables an initial value (initialize them). This prevents an attempt to read from uninitialized space which is the bane of new C programmers. (it will save you a lot of headaches). Attempting to read from an uninitialized variable is **Undefined Behavior**. That can result in anything from slipping by unnoticed, to causing your program to crash. It is to be avoided.

Also, as I explained in the comment, in C, the function `main()` is type `int` and it returns a value to its caller (usually the shell, or another program). When using `main` without arguments, the proper form is:

```
int main (void)
```

When accepting arguments, the proper form is:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

In either case, it should return a **positive** value upon completion. A `return 0;` at the end is all that is required. `exit (0);` is another function you can use to return a value. You will also see the form of `main` with arguments written as:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

The first and second forms are the practical equivalents of each other, the first recognizing that an array passed to a function in C will decay to a pointer. But for now, just understand that they are equivalent.

You also have an error in your `my_power` calculation. `int temp = doom1;` should be `int temp = 1;` Your calculation was returning a value twice the actual product.

Your style of syntax is up to you, but I would suggest that expanding your syntax a little by using discretionary spaces and lines will make your code much more readable and make finding errors a bit easier. Here is an example regarding all of these points:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int my_power (int doom1, int doom2);

int main (void)
{
    int first = 0;      /* Always initialize your variable to prevent */
    int second = 0;     /* an inadvertant read from an unitialized    */
    int total = 0;      /* value which is Undefined Behavior (bad).   */

    printf ("\n enter the value for the first : ");
    scanf ("%d",&first);

    printf (" enter the value for the second: ");
    scanf ("%d",&second);

    total = my_power (first,second);

    printf ("\n The value for my_power is: %d\n\n", total);

    return 0;
} 

int my_power (int doom1, int doom2)
{
    int temp = 1;
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 1; i <= doom2; i++)
        temp = doom1 * temp;

    return temp;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/simple_function

 enter the value for the first : 2
 enter the value for the second: 7

 The value for my_power is: 128
```

Comment: I was, I must have been a bit sleep punchy. I'll fix that. Thanks.

Comment: What are you getting at?

Comment: Yes, I had the "in addition to ..." language in the first paragraph I deleted in response to Jongware's comment (now deleted)

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to print "power" without parameter

```
printf("The value for power is %d",power);
```

you should do

```
printf("The value for power is %d",total);
```

or

```
printf("The value for power is %d",power(first,second));
```